# ionic2 import model class instance causes no file error

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I am using Ionic2 and have run into the following error:

```
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open "APP LOCATION"\src\Classes\SFIASkill.js'.
```

I've highlight that the error is originating from one of my providers, an more specifically when I instantiate a new instance of a model class.

Here is the model class I'm trying to use

```
export class SFIASkill
{
    ID: number;
    skillName: string;
    skillCode:string;
    subcategoryID: number;
    Levels: Array<LevelWithDescription>;

    constructor(ID: number, skillName: string, skillCode:string,subcategoryID: number)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.skillName = skillName;
        this.skillCode = skillCode;
        this.subcategoryID = subcategoryID;
        this.Levels = new Array<LevelWithDescription>();
    }
}

export class LevelWithDescription {
    Description: string;
    Level: SkillLevel;

    constructor(description: string){
        this.Description = description;                    
    }
}

export class SkillLevel {
    ID: number;
    LevelName: string;
    Autonomy: string;
    BusinessSkills: string;
    Complexity: string;
    Influence: string;


    constructor(id: number, levelName: string, autonomy: string, businessSkills: string, complexity: string, influence: string){
        this.ID = id;
        this.LevelName = levelName;
        this.Autonomy = autonomy;
        this.BusinessSkills = businessSkills;
        this.Complexity = complexity;
        this.Influence = influence;
    }
}
```

Here is the import that I am using on my provider

```
import { SFIASkill, SkillLevel, LevelWithDescription } from '../Classes/SFIASkill';
```

And through commenting out all occurrences I have found that it is this line that is causing the issue.

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:34417/api/Account/UserInfo', options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(response => {        

    if (this.currentUser.Skills.length != 0) {
      this.currentUser.Skills = new Array<SFIASkill>();
    }
    response.skills.forEach(element => {

      let skill = new SFIASkill(element.SFIASkillID, element.Skill.SkillName, element.Skill.SkillCode, element.Skill.SkiilSubCategoryID);
       skill.Levels = new Array<LevelWithDescription>();

      // let level = new LevelWithDescription(element.SkillLevelDescription);
      // level.Level = new SkillLevel(element.SFIASkillLevelID, element.Level.LevelName, element.Level.Autonomy, element.Level.BusinessSkills, element.Level.Complexity, element.Level.Influence);
      // skill.Levels.push(level);

      // this.currentUser.Skills.push(skill);
    });
```

More Specifically whenever I comment out the line:

```
let skill = new SFIASkill(element.SFIASkillID, element.Skill.SkillName, element.Skill.SkillCode, element.Skill.SkiilSubCategoryID);
```

The app loads again but with this line active I get the error I mentioned. Have I missed something? Ive had a look at other questions and most of the time people say that the import is wrong due to case sensitivity but I copied the name of the location from the location itself so I believe that the naming isn't what is wrong.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is the file structure for the involved files

```
src
  app
  assets
  Classes
    SFIASkill(the model class that is causing the error)
  environments
  pages
  providers
    auth-service (The service that is causing the error)
```

Comment: are you sure the relative path in import is correct?

Comment: Hi, @suraj ive just added in a small representative of the file structure detailing where the two files are in relation to each other, I hope this helps you.

Comment: you may have a typo `SFIASkill` and `SFIASKill`.. Notice the case of 'k'

Comment: thank you, I have just tried it with both and I still receive the same error. In order to ensure that it is not a case sensitivity issue I have tried changing the file name and the relative path to all caps, this still results in the error